# Civi Event scheduled reminders error - missing date causes DB syntax error

Tags: civievent, scheduled-reminders, scheduled-job

Event scheduled reminder is not executing.  The error log for scheduled jobs shows failure DB syntax error.

[image: syntax error message]

Answer (score 3):

Problem a result of a reminder that has no sending date.  (see attached image) This error results in a syntax error that **prevents all subsequent reminders from being sent**.  Solution is to add date or disable reminder with no date.   (ConfigAndLog error messages show the ID for the reminder that has the error.)

Will report as a bug with recommendation that reminder cannot be saved without a date.
[image: Reminder with no date]

Comment: Did you report this. If you give me a reference I will add my vote for a fix. Very annoying.